# Generic Text Only Printer Driver Windows 10 ARM64

Tags: printing, printer, zebra-printer

How does one obtain the `Generic - Generic / Text Only` printer driver for Windows 10 on ARM64?  this driver is present on Windows 10 for x86 and x86_64, but I cannot find on Windows 10 on ARM64.

Windows versions checked:

- Windows 10 ARM64 Pro Insiders 21322 (Parallels VM - Apple M1 Processor)
- Windows 10 ARM64 Pro Insiders 21296 (Surface Pro X - Microsoft SQ1 processor)

Since many device drivers (including printer drivers) aren't yet available for Windows 10 ARM64, the `Generic - Generic / Text Only` printer driver can be useful for overriding a driver and talking RAW to a printer (e.g. a Zebra, Star, Citizen, Boca or Epson thermal printer), something I've yet to find out a way to do on ARM64.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Windows Update" to see if that loads it?

Comment: @hdhondt yes I have tried. At time of writing this, the "Find drivers on Windows Updates" doesn't seem do anything helpful yet, at least on both of my copies of Windows on ARM64.

Comment: Got the same issue right now. Ever found a solution?

Comment: No, not yet, but here's a tutorial to build your own: https://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/windowsdriverkitswdk15_10.html

Answer (score -2):

Everything you need is already there in arm64 Windows!

- Add a new printer.
- Select a standard TCP/IP Port that points to the IP of your printer.
- Select "Multiprotocol Print Server" (not "Generic Network Card").
- Send data as RAW over port 9100, usually SNMP won't be supported.
- Use the "Microsoft XPS Class Driver."

Have fun.